# Access scanner from Java or Python (or something else if it's technically motivated) in Linux (but Windows would be nice)

Tags: java, python, image-scanner

I want to write a system for handling important documents in my home. This is the user story for getting a new document:

1. I "Add new document" and am prompted to scan it using my combined printer/scanner.
2. I view the scanned copy to see it's of good enough quality. Which it has.
3. The system tells me to mark it with number N, which I do. I also enter title, document type, description and when the document is no longer needed to be stored (could be never to always keep it).

The problem is accessing the scanner. I do not know what the smoothest way is. Ideally it would support "all" scanners through some kind of standard interface. I do not know if that even exists. Should I do this in Java, Python or something else?

My primary platform is Linux. But if it worked on Windows too, that would be nice. If I manage to create something useful I'll release it as GPL, so it's for a good cause too. ;-)

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, the common interface to scanners is [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The standard interface for scanners is [TWAIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN). If you google for "java twain" or "python twain", you get plenty of useful-looking stuff, e.g.

- http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Java-Twain-image-acquisition
- http://twainmodule.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually, SANE looks like a better bet, if you can get it to work for you. TWAIN is UI+API, SANE is just API.